# Is inline keyword relevant in MPLab?

Tags: c, inline, keyword, pic, mplab

It doesn't seem to be highlighted like other recognized keyword, but I'm not getting compiler errors.

Is there a way to check the assembly?  I'm not in a unix environment so I can't do an objdump, but is there any other way to view the appropriate file?

Thanks!

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you are using either the C18 or C30 compiler.

The C18 compiler does not have an inline keyword, so my assumption is that there is a macro somewhere that is doing this for you.

The C30 compiler does have an inline keyword, so functions should be declared like this:

```
__inline__ void functionname(void) { -----code----- }
```

To check the assembly, you can generate a .lst file for your source code.  Under Project Options, go to the MPLAB ASM30 tab.  Under **Listing Options**, make sure **Enable Listing**, **Include Source Code**, and **Include Assembly** are checked.  Rebuild, and your .lst file will show the disassembly mixed with the C source, and that should show you that your function was properly inlined.